# Date loses leading 0's in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime

I need a string with current date and time in the following format:

"2021-06-02 09:37:38"

```js
const today = `${new Date().toLocaleDateString('sv-se')} ${new Date().toLocaleTimeString('sv-se')}`;
console.log(today);
```

This code runs fine in any browser console I've tried, but if I run this in Node.js the leading 0's are gone in the date part (not the time part):

"2021-6-2 09:37:38"

Is there a nice way to fix this without splitting and padding?

I would prefer to avoid installing any dependencies.

EDIT: Node version is v11.15.0.

Comment: What version of node,  full locale support is pretty recent.

Comment: Yes, version 11, will definitely not have full locale support,.  The latest LTS version 14 does.. Tested your code in 14 and it's fine.  If you really have to stick with 11, then there are other options, but really you should be on the LTS version, just for security reasons.

Comment: If you really need to stick with Node v.11, then you can use this -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/full-icu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to add options as a 2nd parameter to `toLocaleDateString`. For example try this :
`var options = {year: "numeric", month: "2-digit", day: "2-digit"};`

If this does not fit your needs exactly refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Comment: Your suggestion with options works perfectly in Node v11.15.0, thanks!